# When I use delete-operator, there is an error : is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I am writing a simple c++ program that can **input people's information** and their **pet's information**. I use a **new-operator** when I declare the **Person struct**. There is a **Pet struct** inside the Person struct and I also use a **new-operator** to a Pet struct too.

After I execute menu 1 and 2, I thought when I execute menu 3, all of allocated memory will be deleted **but** it shows me the error **is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)**.

How can I delete the dynamic allocated memory in this case?
I need a **help** in **case 3**.

**Here's my code:**

**struct Pet**

```
char PetName[30]; 

int PetAge;
```

**struct Person**

```
char Name[30]; 

int Age; 

int PetNum;

Pet *PET;
```

void InputData(Person *p, int PeopleNum);

static int PeopleNum = 0;

static int PetNum = 0;

**void main() :**

```
cout << "Input People Number: ";
cin >> PeopleNum;
Person *Ps = new Person[PeopleNum];

while (1) {
    cout << "\n\n===== Menu =====\n";
    cout << "1. InputData\n" << "2. View List\n" << "3. End\n" << endl;
    cout << "Select Number : ";

    int n = 0;
    cin >> n;

    switch (n) {
    case 1: {
        InputData(Ps, PeopleNum);
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        for (int i = 0; i < PeopleNum; i++) {
            cout << "\n==========================\n";
            cout << "Peole["<<i+1<<"] Name: " << Ps->Name << "   Age: " << Ps->Age << endl;
            cout << "==========================\n";
            for (int j = 0; j < Ps->PetNum; j++) {
                cout << "Pet[" << j + 1 << "] Name: " << Ps->PET->PetName << "   Age: " << Ps->PET->PetAge << endl;
                Ps->PET++;
            }
            Ps++;
        }
        cout << "==========================\n";
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        for (int i = 0; i < PeopleNum; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Ps->PetNum; j++) {
                delete[](Ps->PET);
                Ps->PET++;
            }
            delete[]Ps;
            Ps++;
        }

        cout << "\nEnd the programm" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

**void InputData(Person *p, int PeopleNum) :**

```
for (int i = 0; i < PeopleNum; i++) {
    cout << "\nInput *" << i + 1 << "'s Name and Age.\n";
    cout << "Name : ";
    InputValue(p->Name);
    cout << "Age : ";
    InputValue(p->Age);

    cout << "Input Pet Number: ";
    InputValue(p->PetNum);
    PetNum = p->PetNum;

    p->PET = new Pet[p->PetNum];

    cout << "\n\n\n* Input Pet's name and age.\n";
    
    for (int j = 0; j < p->PetNum; j++) {
        cout << "Pet's Name : ";
        InputValue(p->PET->PetName); 
        cout << "Pet's Age : ";
        InputValue(p->PET->PetAge);
        cout << "\n";

        p->PET++;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < p->PetNum; j++) {
        p->PET--;
    }
    p++;
}
```

Comment: Note that you are not using `new`/`delete` _operators_, but _expressions_. These are different things in C++, which is often confusing for beginners. Anyway, I would suggest rewriting the code without the need to use `new`/`delete`. In modern C++, when you don't implement some low-level stuff, there is rarely any need to use `new` and `delete` manually.

Comment: You use `new` once when creating `PET`, but the you go and `delete` no less than `Ps->PetNum` times, and only one of those times with the `PET` that `new` created.

Comment: Side note: use indexing (e.g. `p->PET[i]`) instead of incrementing pointers.

Comment: @DanielLangr I'm studying how to use the dynamic memory. However, thank you so much for your advice!!

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you so much!! I'll try it again:D